# Java :Generate random numbers between minimum and a maximum values

Tags: java, random, numbers, user-input

This is the exercise I am stuck with :

> Ask user for minimum, maximum (inclusive) and how many (count) random
> numbers user wants to generate. Makes sure minimum is not larger than
> maximum and count is not negative. Display error message if inputs are
> invalid. If all is fine then generate the random numbers and print
> them out, comma-separated on a single line.

I wrote the code in many ways. I can never get the `for` loop to print the Random numbers.

```
package randnumsmany;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandNumsMany {

    public static double getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
        return (int) ((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter minimum :");
        int min = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter maximum :");
        int max = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter number generated :");
        int num = input.nextInt();

        int[] rand = new int[num];

        for (int i = 0; i == num - 1; i++) {
            rand[i] = (int) getRandomNumber(min, max);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i == num - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(rand[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("How many generated: " + num);    
    }
}
```

Comment: The second argument to your for-loops is wrong. The loop will only continue as long as `i` is equal to `num-1`, which is never the case, so the loop never executes

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)` in both loops

Comment: Also, your code is currently not implementing the _minimum is not larger than maximum_ and _count is not negative_ part of the specification.

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not need an array for it. You can simply print all the numbers when they are calculated. Since you have to print them separated by a comma, you can print all but the last one followed by a comma and then print the last one without a comma.
2. Also, you can use an infinite loop to check the validity of inputs. If the inputs are valid, you can break the loop otherwise because of the loop, the inputs will be requested again.
3. Also, since the maximum needs to be inclusive, your formula to calculate the random number should be `(int) (Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int min, max, num;

        System.out.print("Enter minimum: ");
        min = input.nextInt();

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter maximum: ");
            max = input.nextInt();

            if (min > max) {
                System.out.println("Minimum can not be larger than maximum");
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter number generated: ");
            num = input.nextInt();
            if (num < 0) {
                System.out.println("The count can not be negative");
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        // Print all but the last number followed by a comma
        for (int i = 1; i <= num - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(getRandomNumber(min, max) + ", ");
        }

        // Print the last number without a comma
        System.out.print(getRandomNumber(min, max));
    }

    public static int getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
        return (int) (Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter minimum: 10
Enter maximum: 20
Enter number generated: 20
19, 17, 13, 17, 16, 19, 12, 15, 20, 15, 17, 17, 19, 12, 13, 10, 16, 12, 14, 17
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter minimum: 10
Enter maximum: 5
Minimum can not be larger than maximum
Enter maximum: 20
Enter number generated: -10
The count can not be negative
Enter number generated: 5
18, 16, 11, 11, 13
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// randomStream(n, min, max): e.g using stream, generate n number between min and max
// randomRandom(min, max) example of getting one random number between min and max
// randomMath(min, max): other way similar to randomRandom(min, max)
// randomThreadLocalRandom(): just for a random number without constrain
// It is effective way to use stream when many random number are needed.
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
    
    public class Randomize {
        public static void main(String args[]){
            randomStream(2, 3, 10);
            randomRandom(3, 10);
            randomMath(3, 10);
        }
        
        // (generate random number between 0.0 and 1.0) * (max - min +(1 or 0)) + min
        
        // length: how much number you want to generate
        public static void randomStream( int length, int min, int max){ 
            System.out.println("using random as Stream");
            Random rand = new Random();
            int[] random = rand.ints(length, min, max).toArray(); 
            System.out.print("As integer: ");
            for(int i : random)  
                System.out.print(i+"; "); 
            System.out.println("");
            
            double[] randomD = ThreadLocalRandom.current().doubles(length, min, max).toArray();
            System.out.print("As double: "); 
            for(double d : randomD) 
                System.out.print(d+"; "); 
            System.out.println("");
        }
        
        public static void randomRandom(int min, int max){
            System.out.println("using Random");
            Random rand = new Random();
        
            int int_random = min + rand.nextInt(max-min);
            System.out.println("As integer: "+ int_random);
            
            double double_random = min + rand.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("As double: "+double_random);
        }
        
        public static void randomMath(int min, int max){
            System.out.println("using Math:");
            int random_int = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
            System.out.println("As integer: "+random_int);
            
            double random_double = Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min; 
            System.out.println("As double: "+ random_double);
        }
        
        public static void randomThreadLocalRandom(){
            int int_random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt();  
            System.out.println("As Integers: " + int_random); 
            
            double double_rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(); 
            System.out.println("As Doubles: " + double_rand); 
        }
    }
//
```